# Totally download image before showing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there a way to download images inside an HTML page before showing the page? Because I got an issue where the div underneath doesn't show up correctly. I am pretty sure that it is due to the image loading after the page was shown. I have no issue locally, but once I deploy it with Heroku, I have a visual error like so:

[image: on heroku]

The local version:

[image: locally]

Would anyone have an idea on how to download them before showing the rest of the page? I tried to use the following JavaScript but it didn't work:

```
preload([
     './webapp/dist/images/chantier1.jpg',
     './webapp/dist/images/chantier2.jpg',
     './webapp/dist/images/chantier3.jpg'
 ]);

 function preload(arrayOfImages) {
     $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
         $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
         // Alternatively you could use:
         // (new Image()).src = this;
     });
 }
```

Thank you for your help and time

Comment: just use it inside `$(window).load(function() {
});`

Comment: What is the dimension of these images? Big data takes time. In cases where I care a lot I will just hide the images until they are finished loading using the `load` event.

Comment: I don't think it's a loading issue - everything loads well as I can see. Check your css.

Comment: I tried to put it in $(window).load(function() { }); but it didn't work :/ Those are pretty big images so it is probably linked to that. I'll try to play with the css...

Comment: Just add a height size to your header :) I suppose your header images are in same size

Comment: Honestly it looks like a css issue at first glance.

Comment: `$(window).load` is deprecated .... and woudn't help if images are loaded using any ajax

Answer (score 0):

a fast way to do it, by the way i think it's really strange that an image load delay can create this kind of view problem:

```js
$(window).load(function() { 
    $('.loader').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```css
img{
  width: 100%
}
.loader{
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
p{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/39/wdXqHcTwSTmLuKOGz92L_Landscape.jpg">
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/1029/landscape-mountains-nature-clouds.jpg">
<div class="loader">
     <p> loading </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do Using preload link tag:

```
<link rel = "preload" href = "path/to/image.png" as = "image">
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to set the height of the images container and the width and height on img tags.